# Devise+activeadmin+doorkeeper - Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I am not able to generate access token for applications created in /oauth/applications

i have done following changes in the doorkeeper initializer file

**doorkeeper.rb**

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end
```

when i try to authorize an app from /oauth/applications i get the following error

```
Started GET "/oauth/authorize?client_id=87122ba040e56b44477a69b189ad809bf663c374f8cc513dd55bff81c07f030b&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3001%2Fauth%2Fapi_provider%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-12 12:04:52 +0530
Processing by Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"client_id"=>"87122ba040e56b44477a69b189ad809bf663c374f8cc513dd55bff81c07f030b", "redirect_uri"=>"http://localhost:3001/auth/api_provider/callback", "response_type"=>"code", "scope"=>""}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_resource_owner! rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-12 12:04:52 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-12 12:04:52 +0530
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 136ms (Views: 135.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

i want to generate authentication token to authorize the apps to use api calls for my application

tried to follow railscast episode on [Doorkeeper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN9BylV81rw)

And this is my [application](https://github.com/shubhangisingh/api_provider)

Answer (score 8):

The resource_owner_authenticator should be replaced by below block to generate auth tockns for your client apps

```
resource_owner_authenticator do |routes|
 current_user || warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user)
end
```

Comment: This worked, can you include a line or two about what's going on here? I get how devise's current_user method replaced `User.find_by_id session[:user_id]`.